# How to remove just the set of numbers with / in between among other strings?

Tags: r, regex, string, text-mining

I need to extract the blood pressure values from a text note that is typically reported as one larger number, "/" over a smaller number, with the units mm HG (it's not a fraction, and only written as such).  In the 4 examples below, I want to extract 114/46, 135/67, 109/50 and 188/98 only, without space before or after and place the top number in column called SBP, and the bottom number into a column called DBP. 
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
bb <- c("PATIENT/TEST INFORMATION (m2): 1.61 m2\n BP (mm Hg): 114/46 HR 60 (bpm)", "PATIENT/TEST INFORMATION:\ 63\n Weight (lb): 100\nBSA (m2): 1.44 m2\nBP (mm Hg): 135/67 HR 75 (bpm)", "PATIENT/TEST INFORMATION:\nIndication: Coronary artery disease. Hypertension. Myocardial infarction.\nWeight (lb): 146\nBP (mm Hg): 109/50 HR (bpm)", "PATIENT/TEST INFORMATION:\nIndication: Aortic stenosis. Congestive heart failure. Shortness of breath.\nHeight: (in) 64\nWeight (lb): 165\nBSA (m2): 1.80 m2\nBP (mm Hg): 188/98 HR 140 (bpm) ")   

BP <- head(bb,4)
dput(bb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R` to extract the required values, and then with `read.table`, create a two column data.frame

```
read.table(text = regmatches(bb, regexpr('\\d+/\\d+', bb)), 
      sep="/", header =  FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#   V1 V2
#1 114 46
#2 135 67
#3 109 50
#4 188 98
```

---

Or using `strcapture` from `base R`

```
strcapture( "(\\d+)\\/(\\d+)", bb, data.frame(X1 = integer(), X2 = integer()))
#   X1 X2
#1 114 46
#2 135 67
#3 109 50
#4 188 98
```

To create this as new columnss in the original data.frame, use either `cbind` to bind the output with the original dataset

```
cbind(data, read.table(text = ...))
```

Or

```
data[c("V1", "V2")] <- read.table(text = ...)
```

---

Or using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(bb) %>%
      extract(bb, into = c("X1", "X2"), ".*\\b(\\d+)/(\\d+).*", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#     X1    X2
#  <int> <int>
#1   114    46
#2   135    67
#3   109    50
#4   188    98
```

If we don't want to remove the original column, use `remove = FALSE` in `extract`

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution:

```
setNames(data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(trimws(gsub("[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]][^0-9]+", "", 

     gsub("HR.*", "", paste0("BP", lapply(strsplit(bb, "BP"), '[', 2)))), "both"), "/"))),

     c("SBP", "DBP"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help.  I tried it and liked the columns being titled well.  However, the dataframe actually repeated the two columns, and ended up with 4, two with titles SBP  and DBP, and two without any column names.  I also noticed occasionally it would add extra numbers at the end of SBP and/or DPB.  I checked and those numbers did not follow the BP values or elsewhere in the note.  Please let me know if I did not provide enough info in the inquiry or here.  Yout time and assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @Shawn If your data is substantially different to the sample you provided please post more / different data. With what is provided I am afraid this is the best I can do. If you run this over the provided sample the end result is a single dataframe with two vectors "SBP", "DBP", as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_match` and select numbers which has `/` in between

```
as.data.frame(stringr::str_match(bb, "(\\d+)/(\\d+)")[, 2:3])

#   X1 X2
#1 114 46
#2 135 67
#3 109 50
#4 188 98
```

---

In base R, we can extract the numbers that follow the pattern `a/b`, split them on `'/'` and form two columns.

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(sub(".*?(\\d+/\\d+).*", "\\1", bb), "/")))
```

You can give them the column names as per your choice using `setNames` or any other method.

Comment: Thank you this worked readily!  Is there a way to place the new two columns as new columns 11 and 12 in the original dataframe?  If not, I can always bind these two columns to the master dataset.

Comment: You could do `cbind(df, as.data.frame.....rest of the code)`